# Panel body height is not expanding with html body

Tags: html, css

Hiii Everyone,

I have multiple divs.Inside each div there will be panel body and its footer.What happening is based on panel body content its not adjusting instead its overlapped panel footer above panel body.Below is my screenshot

[image]

In the above image u can understand what is happening.And my example code is

```
<main class="page-content content-wrap" style="background-color:#E9EDF2;height:auto">
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div id="five_radio_question">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <br/><br/>
                <h2 style="color:#C32F10"><b>Reorder Paragraphs</b></h2><br/>
                <div class="panel-body" style="background-color:#EFAD4D;color:#fff;border-radius:4px;padding:1px">
                    <h4>The text bubbles in the left panel have been placed in a random order. Restore the original order by dragging the text bubbles from the left panel to the right panel.</h4>
                </div>      
                <br/>
                <p style="font-size:14px">
                    Write 1-5 next to each paragraph to indicate the order you think is correct.
                </p>            
                Contentss
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <h3 style="float:left"> Question 5 of 14</h3>
            <div style="float:right">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg first_ques_button4">
                    Previous Question
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg second_ques_button4">
                    Next Question
                </button>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

And also I tried with css in somany ways with the help of google.And My issue is not resolved.

```
#main-wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
body {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Please anyone help me to get out of this issue.Thanks in advance..

Comment: please share a live view in a fiddle or etc, also still not clear what is your problem exactly.

Comment: Add a working demo

Comment: I guess the "overlapping" is being caused by your usage of the `float`. Floating causes the element to ignore the normal flow. See [MDN docs - float](https://kapeli.com/dash_share?docset_file=CSS&docset_name=CSS&path=developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float.html&platform=css&repo=Main&source=developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Comment: You HTML is malformed. Missing a closing DIV tag. You should use `body {min-height: 100vh;}`  The`min-height: 100%` has no effect.

Comment: Without float how can I add alignment for buttons and If I remove panel footer height will be auto based on content in panel body

Comment: wait Ill add jsfiddle demo

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q31fa3pc/